# python regular expression to get a token from the page

Tags: python, python-re

I am trying to automate a few things in Python instead of manually doing the same thing again and again. Currently, I am stuck find the 'csrfmiddlewaretoken' from a site called dnsdumpster.com. I have written a regular expression for it, but it returns the whole tag that contains the 'csrfmiddlewaretoken'. I am only interested in the token alone (which is inside the 'value' parameters of the HTML tag). This is my code:

```
import requests
import re

headers = {
    'Host' : 'dnsdumpster.com',
    'User-Agent' : 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64; rv:80.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/80.0',
    'Accept' : 'text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,*/*;q=0.8',
    'Accept-Language' : 'en-US,en;q=0.5',
    'Accept-Encoding' : 'gzip, deflate',
    'DNT' : '1',
    'Upgrade-Insecure-Requests' : '1',
    'Connection' : 'close'
}

proxies = {
    'http' : 'http://127.0.0.1:8080'
}

with requests.Session() as s:
    url = 'https://dnsdumpster.com'
    response = s.get(url, headers=headers, proxies=proxies)
    response.encoding = 'utf-8' # Optional: requests infers this internally
    body = response.text
    csrfmiddlewaretoken = re.search('name="csrfmiddlewaretoken" value="[0-9a-zA-z]+', body)
    print(csrfmiddlewaretoken)
    # Embarassing way of getting the token
    print(body[2417:2481])
```

I need help with the regular expression to get the token value alone.

Comment: I would recommend using a third-party library to extract something like this rather than build your own regular expression: https://pypi.org/project/beautifulsoup4/

Comment: If you're trying to parse HTML, then you should use an HTML parser instead of relying on a regex.  It's a bit wordier, but it's much more robust.  Python has a simple parser built in in the `html.parser` module, but BeautifulSoup is well-respected.

Answer (score 0):

Using beautiful soup, the preferred method:

```py
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

soup = BeautifulSoup(body, 'html.parser') #body is your response.text or your HTML string
csrf = soup.find("meta",  attrs={'name': "csrfmiddlewaretoken"})
token = csrf["content"] if csrf else None
```

Using regex:

```py
csrfmiddlewaretoken = re.search('name="csrfmiddlewaretoken" value="[0-9a-zA-z]+', body)
token = None
if csrfmiddlewaretoken:
    token = csrfmiddlewaretoken.group().split(' value="')[-1]
```

In both the methods, the `token` variable will contain the value of the `meta` tag with `name=csrfmiddlewaretoken`...

Comment: I get the following error: TypeError: find() got multiple values for argument 'name'

Comment: sorry, my bad... Made the changes, please check now...

Answer (score 0):

You could use a capture group in the regex by adding parentheses

```
match = re.search('name="csrfmiddlewaretoken" value="([0-9a-zA-z]+)', body)
if match:
    csrfmiddlewaretoken = match.group(1)
else:
    # deal with it
```

The risk is that minor changes in the returned page could break your search. XML attributes are unordered and the page could switch switch them around while still technically not changing the page at all.